# Numeración automática

Tags: java, java-swing

Quisiera que ese textfield se enumere solo en un formato parecido a esto => 0001 , 0002 , así sucesivamente.

[image: Así tengo el formulario]

Comment: Recuerda que tu pregunta no debe parecer [un ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433): muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: Hola buen día, para agregar nueva información, [edit] tu pregunta, agrega el código o información nueva que veas relevante. No utilices el área de respuestas para agregar mas información.

Answer (score 2):

Esta el de toda la vida con `addKeyListener`, usando `keyTyped` y `keyReleased` , con estos se puede lograr escribir por ejemplo 1 y que escriba 0001 y así sucesivamente)

Código:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0000"); // el formato de los 4 ceros

JTextField field = new JTextField();
field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_DELETE && !Character.isDigit(e.getKeyChar())) {
            e.consume(); return;
        }
    }
        
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(!field.getText().isEmpty()) {
            field.setText(decimalFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(field.getText())));
        }
    }
        
});
```

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, field);`

No encontré una manera fácil para esto, probé incluso con JFormattedTextField y no sirve, en otros foros usan los eventos con JTextField también, me imagino que es una solución aceptada para este tipo de cosas.